# Haskell No instance for (Fractional a0) arising

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in Haskell:

```
powmod base 1 m = mod base m
powmod base exp m | even exp  = mod (pow2 * pow2) m
                  | otherwise = mod (base * powmod base (exp - 1) m) m
     where
        pow2 = powmod base (div exp 2) m

part1 j n 0 = 0
part1 j n k = (part1 j n (k-1)) + (powmod 16 (n-k) r)/r
   where
     r = 8*k+j
```

The code is loaded without any problem on ghci. The problem comes when I try to call the function part1 as:

```
part1 4 10 4
```

I get:

> No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of `it' The type
>   variable`a0' is ambiguous Note: there are several potential
>   instances:   instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
>       -- Defined in `GHC.Real'   instance Fractional Double -- Defined in`GHC.Float'   instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
>   In the first argument of`print', namely `it' In a stmt of an
>   interactive GHCi command: print it

I don't understand this problem. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your problem here is a very common one - it roots into you mixing `(/)` with `Integral` operations like `mod` - this leads to two constraints: one for `Integral` and one for `Fractional` (the `(/)`) - but there is no basic number type which is an instance of both of them - so you end up with *unsolvable* constraints and GHC(i) will not find a matching instance and complain.

Most of this becomes obvious if you signatures - yes you don't have to but as you can see here it's valuable to do so anyway.

Assuming you want to work over `Integer` you get this:

```
part1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
part1 j n 0 = 0
part1 j n k = (part1 j n (k-1)) + (powmod 16 (n-k) r) `div` r
   where
     r = 8*k+j
```

note that I replaced `(/)` with `div`? Haskell points you to this as soon as you include expected types.

*also* note that of course

```
part1 :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

will work as well

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but what if I actually want the return type from part1 to be a fractional? I tried with "part1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Float" but taht did not work

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I needed some fromIntegral conversions. Final code:

```
part1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Double
part1 j n 0 = 0
part1 j n k =  (part1 j n (k-1)) + (fromIntegral (powmod 16 (n-k) r)) / fromIntegral r
 where
   r = 8*k+j
```